# Пишу сайт на котором .select для смены языка но он сьехал ниже чем нужно . Задача здвинуть .select

Tags: html, css, select

```css
.icon6{
    margin-left:61px ;
    border:0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    flex:auto;
    width: 48px; ;
    height: 94px; ;
}

button{

     border:0;
    padding:0;
}

.buton{

    font-family:Montserrat;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height:25px; 
    height: 21px;

   
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button  class="buton"><select class="icon6">
      <option value="en">EN</option>
      <option value="ua">UA</option>
</select></button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите select из button и задайте ему высоту как у других кнопок.

Будет полезно изучить позиционирование элементов с помощью [flexbox](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/)

Comment: ну и непонятно, как это к ответу применить.

Comment: @PetLinux лучше?